# Convert Amount (currency ) field into words

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

Example:

1345

One thousand three hundred and forty five.

Answer (score 2):

With Apex you can convert number to words : http://salesforcewithkiran.blogspot.in/2013/05/number-to-words-in-apex.html

Comment: The code will need some small updates when dealing with sextillion and sexdecillion

Comment: Yeah you're right. I don't know what's the numbers the author want to convert but the link given is just an example and he may have to do some updates.